# Match database items exactly once in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Let's say there is a simple database of people in Prolog

```
person(john).
person(mary).    
person(john).
person(susan).
```

I need to match the entires exactly once:

```
john-mary, john-john, john-susan, mary-john, mary-susan, john-susan
```

I tried coming up with something like this:

```
match:- person(X),!,person(Y),   write(X),write(-), write(Y),nl.
run:- person(X), match(X), fail.
```

But it's matching many times, and matches a person to him/herself, which shouldn't be.

Basically, what I need is to iterate over all Xs and make Prolog to look strictly "below" for Ys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
person(john).
person(mary).    
person(john).
person(susan).    

match :- findall(P,person(P),People), match_all(People).

match_all([_]) :- !.
match_all([P|People]) :- match_2(P,People), match_all(People).

match_2(_,[]) :- !.
match_2(P1,[P2|People]) :- format('~a-~a~n',[P1,P2]), match_2(P1,People).

?- match.
```

Comment: Maybe there shouldn't be "_" in the first line?

Comment: And on the second line the last subgoal should be match_all(People). Then everything works!. Thank you!

Comment: The `_` in the end of recursion clause is ok, the last goal was indeed missing.

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution would be to number your people:

```
person(1, john).
person(2, mary).
person(3, john).
person(4, susan).
```

Then you could match people like this:

```
match(X-Y) :-
  person(I, X), person(J, Y), I < J.
```

Since you have two `john` entries, I'm not sure any other solution is going to work. Normally you could fake an ordering using `@>/2` but that would require your atoms to be unique, and since they aren't, it would prevent the `john-john` solution.

**Edit**: Since we're willing to use `findall/3` to materialize the database of people, we can treat this as a list problem and find a functional solution. Let's get all the combinations in a list:

```
combinations([X|Rest], X, Y) :- member(Y, Rest).
combinations([_|Rest], X, Y) :- combinations(Rest, X, Y).
```

With this predicate in hand, we can find the solution:

```
combined_folks(People) :-
  findall(P, person(P), Persons),
  findall(X-Y, combinations(Persons, X, Y), People).

?- combined_folks(X).
X = [john-mary, john-john, john-susan, mary-john, mary-susan, john-susan].
```

That actually turned out to be pretty clean!

Comment: That would be a way out, but I'm not allowed to make any changes to the original database. Is there a way to generate a new database with unique numbers?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but at that point it might be simpler to just write something that can give you permutations of a list and use `bagof/3` to get all the people and pass them as a list.

Comment: I used findall/3 for that purpose. Now, when I have a list, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Go over the list; start at the beginning, matching each element only with elements coming AFTER it in the list.

Comment: I couldn't leave the problem alone. :)